# Magento - Newly added products not showing

Tags: php, magento, product

I have created a new product from Magento backend but it does not show up under relevant category or in the product page it self. i.e If I type the product url key it goes to a 404 page.

This is just a simple product and I checked the following,

```
Product enabled : Yes

Visibility : Catalog, search

Product Images : All good

Quantity Available : 9999999

Stock Availability : In Stock

Assign to a category : Yes (I even went to Manage Category to see product is under Category products and its there)

Product in web sites : Assigned

Cache : Cleared 10 X times

Indexing : Done
```

I did one more thing I looked at `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php` and add following line in  `getProductCollection()` function before the `return $collection`

```
var_dump($collection->getAllIds());
```

Then I went to the category page and I could see var_dump output all product IDs assign to that category but still new product I is was not there :(

This is really frustrating took my whole day and no luck, any ideas?

UPDATE :

Just found that I could manually navigate to the product page by `http://my.host/catalog/product/view/id/881`

But in the page it says "...this item is currently unavailable" just dig in to the code and to see why this message is showing and found that, `$_product->isSaleable()` returns false.

But I'm not sure weather that has something to with product is not visible on category and cannot navigate sing URL Key

Comment: Indexing - the thing you are missing man

Comment: Yep let me add that too :)

Comment: category to whom product is assigned is subcat of root category of store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally manage to fix the issue. I'll explain what I did to fix this because it might help someone else as well.

Like I said in my question I did my checklist. But `$_product->isSaleable()` was returning `false`.

So I had to dig in to the code and found that  `$_product->isSaleable()` is set in `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Status::assignProduct()`.

```
public function assignProduct(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product, $stockId = 1, $stockStatus = null)
    {
        if (is_null($stockStatus)) {
            $websiteId = $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
            $status = $this->getProductStatus($product->getId(), $websiteId, $stockId);
            $stockStatus = isset($status[$product->getId()]) ? $status[$product->getId()] : null;
        }

        $product->setIsSalable($stockStatus);

        return $this;
    }
```

Then I found that `$this->getProductStatus();` returned an empty array, and the reason for that is there are no entries  in `cataloginventory_stock_status` table for my new product.

This table is only get updated when **Stock Status index** was rebuilt, which was all **Green** and  **"Ready"** in Magento admin, but it was not really **"Ready"** :(.

So I ran `shell/indexer.php --reindexall` to manually re-build all my indexes, which also updated `cataloginventory_stock_status` table.

Finally I could see my products. Yey!!

@Kingshuk Deb - So you are correct, it was indexing, but Magento admin said it was all good, which mislead me from the beginning.